# How to change kendo ui scheduler event color programmatically

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I want to change kendo ui scheduler event color based on a logic. Please find the sample implementation as below.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@lilan123/UPuDE/4

Basically What I want is when I click on create button I want to add events and every event should have a different color. i tried to create the event as below adding color option but it doesn't work in that way.

```
attendees: '1',
start: new Date("2015/6/8"),
end: new Date("2015/6/8"),
title: "Off Day",
isAllDay: true,
color:'#0055A7'
```

Thanks

Lilan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with a solution and it solve my issue,

please find the sample from

http://dojo.telerik.com/@lilan123/AJuqa

Regards, 
Lilan